# Send event to Google Analytics from GWT using JSNI

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-analytics, jsni

I have all the Google Analytics code between the  and  in my HTML file. These stats are processed correctly.

After a onclick event on my , function below is called and I would like to send an event to Google Analytics, but it is never received. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static native void googleAnalyticsEvent(String boxId) /*-{
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', boxId , 'Click']);
}-*/;
```

FYI, if I replace this code for the below, an alert is correctly displayed:

```
public static native void googleAnalyticsEvent(String boxId) /*-{
alert(boxId);
}-*/;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
public static native void googleAnalyticsEvent(String boxId) /*-{
    $wnd._gaq.push(['_trackEvent', boxId , 'Click']);
}-*/;
```

From https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideCodingBasics#DevGuideJavaScriptNativeInterface

> "Note that the code did not reference the JavaScript window object
>   directly inside the method. When accessing the browser's window and
>   document objects from JSNI, you must reference them as $wnd and $doc,
>   respectively. Your compiled script runs in a nested frame, and $wnd
>   and $doc are automatically initialized to correctly refer to the host
>   page's window and document."